# Condition for Equality of Two Integrals

Tags: integration

If I have an arbitrary scalar function **f(x,y,z)** that is non-zero and positive within a volume $V$ of $\Bbb R^3$, and I have a constraint that requires

$$\int_{V} f(x,y,z)\, dV =\int_{V} f(x,y,z) \cdot g(x,y,z)\, dV$$

where **g(x,y,z)** is a unique given function and **f(x,y,z)**>0 inside $V$ and =0 outside $V$ .

It would appear to me that this requires **g(x,y,z)=1** given that **f(x,y,z)** is arbitrary.

What would be the best way to strictly prove this mathematically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since $g$ is fixed it can come before the integral(as any number would).

Comment: **g** is not a number but a function of x,y.x as well, only that it is a unique, given function (I changed the formulation in the OP in this respect) but the equation should hold for arbitrary **f(x,y,z)**

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a uniqueness theorem for integration? This would reduce the problem to identifying the g function as a multiplicative identity by inspection which is 1.